# Set content of HTML <span> with Javascript

Tags: javascript, dhtml, html

In a webpage I am calling a WebService that gives me an integer value.  I need to display this value in a block of text.  I am currently using an HTML `<span>`.

So far, I've found two methods of putting my value in a span.  `innerText()` is an IE proprietary way of doing it and `innerHTML()` is a non-standards compliant way, although widely supported.

What is the correct standards compliant way of setting the text between `<span>` and `</span>` from Javascript?

Comment: As of HTML5, `innerHTML` **is** a part of the Spec http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#innerhtml and supported by all browsers (minus *some* issues in IE (of all browsers) with the *setter* on `table` and `select` elements/sub-elements)

Answer (score 68, accepted):

This is standards compliant and cross-browser safe.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/kv9pw/

```
var span = document.getElementById('someID');

while( span.firstChild ) {
    span.removeChild( span.firstChild );
}
span.appendChild( document.createTextNode("some new content") );
```

Answer (score 79):

With modern browsers, you can set the `textContent` property, see [Node.textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent):

```
var span = document.getElementById("myspan");
span.textContent = "some text";
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer because it's simpler to read and cleaner

Answer (score 24):

To do it without using a JavaScript library such as jQuery, you'd do it like this:

```
var span = document.getElementById("myspan"),
    text = document.createTextNode(''+intValue);
span.innerHTML = ''; // clear existing
span.appendChild(text);
```

If you do want to use jQuery, it's just this:

```
$("#myspan").text(''+intValue);
```

Comment: You can just do `.text(intValue)`.  The forced string conversion by concatenation isn't necessary.

Answer (score 3):

The Maximally Standards Compliant way to do it is to create a text node containing the text you want and append it to the span (removing any currently extant text nodes).

The way I would actually do it is to use jQuery's `.text()`.