# Copy span content within a hierarchy, to a variable

Tags: javascript, html, variables, getelementsbyclassname

I have the numeric value in a span (.amount), in hierarchy with other divs (.coins and .description).

What I would like to do:

1 - Copy the contents of <.amount> to a variable called $coins

2 - Update a var $total with the sum of $coins + $wallet

3 - Copy the var $total and show it in a Span with ID #total

Below is the idea of the process, but it is not a code itself.

Very thanks!

```
<div class="coins">
    <div class="description">
        <span class="amount">152</span>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    var coins = 152 //content of the hierarchy class ".coins .amount"
    var wallet = 1000
    var total = coins + wallet
</script>

Your Total: <span id="total">$total</span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. [How to get content of span](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10343838/get-value-of-span-text)
2. [How to set content in span](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4784568/set-content-of-html-span-with-javascript)

   ```
   <div class="coins">
       <div class="description">
           <span id="amount">152</span>
       </div>

       <p>Your Total: <span id="total"></span></p>
   </div>

   <script>
           var coins = Number(document.getElementById("amount").innerText)
           var wallet = 1000
           var total = coins + wallet

           document.getElementById("total").innerText = total
   </script>
   ```

Comment: Thanks Adrien!!
Is there a possibility to use the class, without changing to ID?
And inform the hierarchy, something like "document.getElement... (".coin. amount")"
Would it work that way?

Comment: Yes you can use query selector `document.querySelector(".coin .amout").innerText`